# How to have a string that results from a JS function appear in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a div where on page load, it displays a string of text that is randomly selected from a set of predefined strings.

My assumption would be to make an array in JS with the strings, and then have a function that selects one of them. How would I take the value that is received from doing that, and have it display in the div?

Thanks!

Comment: You simply need a `Math.rand` on your index range and then set the `html()` of the `div` with the matched `Array` index entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
words=['11111','2222','3333'];
var selected= words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)];
document.getElementsByClassName('word')[0].textContent=selected;
```

( HTML example)

```
<div class =" word"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a div any where inside your html-body:

```
<div id="javascriptTextHere"></div>
```

Then make a script tag inside the html-head tag:

```
<script>
    //Load your javascript variable string here

    //Suppose your string here is in var abc=....
    document.getElementById("javascriptTextHere").innerText=abc;
</script>
```